# Getting pandas dataframe from json file

Tags: json, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to flatten a JSON file to create a pandas DataFrame. The json output is:

```
{
  'info': {
    'status': [
      
    ],
    'weightcorp': {
      'weight': 4.0
    }
  },
  'results': [
    {
      'instrument': 'A',
      'ts': [
        {
          'date': '2020-12-10',
          'indicators': {
            'Batch': 'Daily',
            'Price': '313.23653',
            'Date': '2020-12-10'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'instrument': 'B',
      'ts': [
        {
          'date': '2020-12-10',
          'indicators': {
            'Batch': 'Weekly',
            'Price': '29.21',
            'Date': '2020-12-10'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The output DataFrame I am looking for is as follow:

| Instrument | Date | Batch | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-12-10 | Daily | 313.23653 |
| B | 2020-12-10 | weekly | 29.21 |

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a custom function to your data:

```
def flatten(d):
    '''
    remove all intermediate dictionaries and list
    '''
    ret = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        # case when value is a dictionary
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sub = flatten(v)
            for kk, vv in sub.items():
                ret[kk] = vv

        # case when value is a list
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for vv in v:
                ret.update(flatten(vv) )    

        # normal key:value pair            
        else: ret[k] = v
    return ret

pd.DataFrame(flatten(v) for v in d['results'])
```

Output:

```
  instrument        date   Batch      Price        Date
0          A  2020-12-10   Daily  313.23653  2020-12-10
1          B  2020-12-10  Weekly      29.21  2020-12-10
```

Comment: do you have a source for your `flatten` func, or can you add a few comments?  This looks super useful

Comment: @anon01 this is close to what I have for my product, since we are pulling data from a source that is similar to this.